# Angular: Pressing Enter Submits Empty Form Regardless of Values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

This may be an iterative question and answer process because I'm not sure which code to paste. I have a custom, advanced search form (which uses ng-submit) that passes a query object into a controller method and calls a service. When the user has entered some input into one or more fields, pressing the submit button (which uses ng-click) successfully calls the methods and submits the query. However, if the user presses enter to submit the form, those same methods are called, but the query object is missing the bound values of the input fields. I've stepped through with breakpoints and have verified that all of the above is what's happening, but am unsure where the problem lies. Is there a difference in Angular's data binding process between ng-click and pressing the enter key? Do I need to call prevent default somewhere? Let me know what code I need to add to this post to help with troubleshooting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who may encounter this problem in the future, it turns out that the problem was that the enter key was firing both the Clear and Submit buttons, as the default behavior for a button is submit. It just happened to be firing the Clear button first, otherwise we never would have noticed the problem. The solution was simply to add "type=button" to the clear button.